# RESTAdapter: how to create resources with nested path

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to know how to create a resource which has nested path in the rest api.

for example given the end point for employee resource,
/companies/{company}/employees/{employee}

How can i create a employee record.
i created a employee model, but the request is going to the top level /.
sending a post request with employee data to /.

should i override pathForType() on the adapter?

Comment: I think ideal solution will be overriding buildURL with a function which builds the required path for this type and calls default function for other types.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I agree that buildURL would be the right place, except there you don't seem to have access to the model being serialized (and thus the parent)

Comment: true, we don't get access to the model getting serialized. I found a fix specific to our case. sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question for others searching for this problem, or accept one of the answers...?

Comment: i accepted the answer provided by @trevthedev. It will work in almost all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about ember router paths then this is how I've done it:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('companies', {path: 'companies/:company_id'}, function () {
       this.resource('employees', {path: 'employees/:employee_id'});
    });
});
```

Which creates something like: index.html/#/companies/{company}/employees/{employee}

This will create CompaniesRoute and EmployeesRoute nested in that route.  This can be nicely viewed in the ember inspector if you've set that up.

Ember will enter CompaniesRoute first and then EmployeesRoute.

See [routing documentation here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/)

If you are talking about sending data to a REST API server then one solution is to override buildURL e.g.:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: "http://whatever", 
        buildURL: function (type, id) {
            var url = [];
            url.push(this.urlPrefix());
            url.push("companies/" + App.companyID + "/employee/" + App.employeeID );
            url.push(this.pathForType(type));
            if (id) {
                url.push(id);
            }
            return url.join('/') + ".json";
        }
    })
});
```

also see [RESTAdapter doco here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html)

Note App.companyID would have to be set before you called buildURL.  I would do this in CompanyRoute and set it like this

```
model: function (params) {
   App.set('companyID', params.company_id);
}
```

Comment: there is no perfect solution for this. In second case, if the apps is accessing 2 different companies at same time, you will face problems.

Comment: Not sure I follow you Ashwin.  If your router is properly configured the models will load in the correct order based on the url and this will enable one to access 2 different companies at the same time - provided you have two unique urls.

Comment: yes, if we can get the company info from url, that will work. But that might not be case always.

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrase your original question to make it clearer a better solution can be proposed.  Company info does not have to come from the URL it can be stored in a variable and accessed like that.

Comment: This approach will work most of the time. What if you want multiple company details at the same time(parallel requests)?

Comment: You could store add the company details to an array that gets built up as the user interacts with your app.  The array could be kept either in memory if the user will not be refreshing the page or in localStorage if it must persist.  Or alternatively sent back the server if it must be shared between multiple users.